# Ajax Control Toolkit Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, visual-studio-2013

I have a textbox with Ajax control extender for autocomplete at my aspx page but I do not know why it is not working.Is there something that I am missing with? I am using VS 2013 by the way.

***Default2.aspx***

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="500" TargetControlID="TextBox1" UseContextKey="True">
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
------------------------------------------------------
**Default2.aspx.cs**
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        string[] address = { "Woodlands", "Rochester", "GreenVile" };

        return(from a in address where a.StartsWith(prefixText,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select a).Take(count).ToArray();
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 1):

what not working please clarify that. By the way, Follow this easy steps it could show you better way how to use it?

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx

**UPDATE**

Please replace this with your `asp:AutoCompleteExtender` and let me know if it works or not?

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
```

also please debug GetCompletionList() this method calling from codebehind.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It have no error but when i run and enter a few letters,the autocomplete does not pop up. I try and redo with the reference of your website but still to no avail

Comment: It should have to work. Something strange you are missing. Have you try to debug `GetCompletionList()` method, that is called from code behind or not?

Comment: sorry but im new.Can you show me a demo code?Do you mean Debug.Writeln(address)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest release on Scriptmanager
[ToolkitScriptManager Removed in v15.1](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager)

Comment: It is sad that this information is not mentioned in the project documentation.